# What is the difference between Äußerung and Aussage?

Tags: grammaticality, semantics

Both mean statement in english. Can someone explain to me what the difference between Äußerung and Aussage?

Comment: This looks off-topic, so no answer, but an *Aussage* is usually something official (to the police, or in court, etc.), while an *Äußerung* ("utterance") is more general, and not necessarily official.

Comment: compare https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Äußerung (*utterance* in english) and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussage (*proposal*)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, maybe you meant *proposition*? I think *statement* will fit more often, though.

Answer (score 3):

*Äußerung* = a *concrete* statement made by a particular speaker at a certain point in time.

*Aussage* = the logical proposition that was expressed by it.

In a parlimentary debate, lots of speakers can make many utterances (Äußerung), most of which convey the same proposition (Aussage). Conversely, a skilled diplomat might make a single finely crafted utterance and appear to mean slightly different propositions to both parties in a negotiation.

Comment: I consider *Äußerung* as far more general, anything observable from the outside qualifies, like clapping hands (*Beifallsäußerung*), groaning (*Unmutsäußerung*), etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Äußerung* translates to *utterance* (as in 'something uttered; a word or words uttered; a cry, animal's call, or the like.'<sup>[1](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/utterance)</sup>) while *Aussage* translates to *proposition*, the difference is the same as in english.

Sometimes this border does not seem to be so sharp and *Äußerung* is used in the meaning 'statement, proposition' as well. This might be the source of your confusion.